# Spring boot web app - not able to pick the static content

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

Spring boot web app with angular bundle was working fine earlier 
Then I added a gradle dependency which is a library that is built within my organization to achieve some api calls. And after that the view/angular build is not picking up by spring boot application.

My project structure looks like below

```
web-app\
    src\main\java\
                   WebApplication.java
            \resources\public\index.html
                      \public\main.5214684651aera5146.js
                      \public\styles.3asd44654e1asd135fsdf.js
                      \public\other-angular-build-files
                       application.properties
```

I haven't added any view controllers/resource handlers by implementing `WebMvcConfigurer`. Spring boot was able to pick the index.html file as welcome page and I was able to see the page on `http://localhost:8080`.

But now it is not working, I have gone though below article and tried with different location of view - `public`, `static`, `resources`, `META-INF\resources` but nothing workout.
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Can someone help how can I debug this issue or override MVC config so that my spring boot should pick the index.html as the welcome page.

Comment: without knowing what that library does th is will be impossible to answer, regardless of the bounty. But a wild guess that library has a configuration with `@EnableWebMvc` on it which disables spring boot auto-configuration for the web part.

Comment: true, but is it possible to override such configuration and assign precedence order?

Comment: You can only not load that configuration but that then defeats the purpose of the library I would say. But still it might be an answer I'm not saying it is **the** answer. Without knowing all that information (however generally my suspicions are right) this is basically impossible to answer and we can only ask questions. So check that library for config classes with `@EnableWebMvc` and ask the library maintainers to remove that.

Comment: That make sense, thanks @Deinum.

Comment: Not sure if you tried with the full path till `index.html`, ie, `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, just to be sure if some configuration is not overriding default pages.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to M. Deinum answer you can try to restrict @ComponentScan only in your app and manually create beans from classes from library

Comment: If the library is a proper library it will include `spring.factories` and friends and then excluding it from an `@Componentscan` won't work.